# How do I make Chrome behave as IE5/IE6

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-6, polyfills

Strange request, I know.

We have a system written 15+ years ago that works only in IE with compatibility mode for IE5. Some of the things that don't work in newer browsers are related to the Javascript engine behaving in a very different way (there are many more issues, but this is the one I'm focusing on right now).

For example, you can do something like

```
document.frames
```

I can make this work in Chrome by extending the prototype of the HTMLDocument DOM object, something like:

```
Object.defineProperty(HTMLDocument.prototype, "frames", { get: function () { return document.getElementsByTagName("iframe"); } })
```

Obviously this won't work for every scenario but it will certainly speed up the process (and prevent having to modify half a million lines of JS).
(Hopefully) this is not a final solution (or the most elegant one) but it can be an initial step to get it working fast before beginning a real refactoring.

I don't expect me being the first person with this approach to make an old app work on new browsers therefore I was wondering how do I solve this in a general way without writing a rule for every IE-specific property/method.

Thanks.

Comment: Interesting question, but too bad library requests are off-topic

Comment: What's the application that you need to get working?  What other specific issues does it have?  Tampermonkey or something might be your best bet.  I don't think you'll find some sort of blanket compatibility mode.

Comment: Back in that day there were so many IE specific hacks that had to be written  I'd hate to have to reverse engineer those. Wouldn't be surprised you see numerous *IE conditional comments* in the html that no other browsers honor

Comment: @CertainPerformance Interesting... one could argue that this is 100% programming-related. -Brad I have access to all the code, it's just too much to try to fix the "right way" at once. -charlietfl they didn't even bother with those, IE was the only browser they ever intended to support.

Comment: @willvv It's easy to make this question comply with the rules. Just remove "if thare are any well known JS libraries..." and rephrase your question to sound more like "how do I do this?"

Comment: @willvv - the problem with asking for recommendation is that you end up with multiple answers being just as right/good as all the other answers. The point of this site is to find the best answer to a programming question

Comment: It's an interesting question, but I would much rather see single points addressed where you experience problems. For now, this is just a blackbox, as we do not know what you need to address and what not. Hell, was javascript not even version 3 at that time?